# Определение реального типа данных в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Требуется определить реальный тип данных в списке содержащий строки вида:

`a = ['-1.8', 'a', 'b', '4']`

Делаю это в цикле с использованием исключений при преобразовании типов данных так:

```
j = []
for i in a:
    try:
        j.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            j.append(float(i))
        except ValueError:
            j.append(i)
print(j)
```

Результатом будет:

```
[-1.8, 'a', 'b', 4]
```

Но не покидает меня стойкое ощущение что есть способ проще. Подскажите плз.

Comment: Цель какая? От этого может зависеть решение.

Comment: Цель из строк списка получить действительный тип данных. В списке всегда str. Соответственно после преобразования str должны остаться str, int стать int из str, а float - float из str

Comment: Использованный duck typing проводит разбор строки (парсинг). Можно его делать и самому с помощью регулярных выражений (или конечным автоматом)

Comment: @MBo, вариант автора явно будет проще и правильнее, чем через парсинг :)

Answer (score 3):

Считаю что этот способ хороший, т.к. гарантирует что данные будут правильно разобраны.

Чтобы ощущение, что есть вариант проще, стало меньше, оберните код разбора в функцию:

```
def parse_str(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            return value


items_1 = ['-1.8', 'a', 'b', '4']
print(items_1)  # ['-1.8', 'a', 'b', '4']

items_2 = [parse_str(x) for x in items_1]
print(items_2)  # [-1.8, 'a', 'b', 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сократить количество кода следующим способом: применять функции из списка. В случае успеха возвращать результат. Если все вызовы закончились неудачей, возвращаем исходное значение:

```
def parse_str(value):
    for f in (int, float):
        try:
            return f(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return value

items = ['-1.8', 'a', 'b', '4']
for v in map(parse_str, items):
    print(type(v), v)
```

> ```
> $ python parse_list.py 
> <class 'float'> -1.8
> <class 'str'> a
> <class 'str'> b
> <class 'int'> 4
> ```

Comment: Хороший ответ :)